# Why does const get added to the string from this pair extracted from an iterator?

Tags: c++

In the following example, does anyone know why `const` gets added to the string giving the error below (same with gcc and VS2008)?

```
#include<utility>
#include<ostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>

class Foo
{
};

class Test
{
public:
    Test() { myMap.insert(std::make_pair("a string", Foo())); }
    std::pair<std::string, Foo>& GetPair() { return *(myMap.begin()); }

private:
    std::map<std::string, Foo> myMap;
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    std::pair<std::string, Foo>& myPair = t.GetPair();
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
t.cpp: In member function 'std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Foo>& Test::GetPair()':
Line 14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Foo>&' from expression of type 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Foo>'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I don't understand why this would be as I'm not using `cbegin()`. Also why would the string be `const`, but not the `Foo`?

Comment: map's key is immutable, hence the error

Comment: You probably need to change the return type to std::pair < const std::string, Foo>& ... of GetPair()

Comment: General comment: Separate interface and underlying data structure in Test. Returning the pair of the map isn't a good style.

Comment: It has to be const so that the key can't be changed.

Comment: A common pitfall - the key of a map is const - std::make_pair(1, expensive_to_copy) is not the value_type of a map<int, expensive_to_copy_type>

Answer (score 2):

Because if you changed the key part of the pair, then it would suddenly be stored in the wrong location in the map's data structure (bucket, position in tree, or something else depending on the structure).  The map doesn't get notified when the key part is changed, so it simply does not allow you to modify it.

On the other hand, the value part is irrelevant to where the pair is stored in the map structure, so you are allowed to change that.